# One controller to another scopes and sharing in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Angular started off easy to understand but today I'm completely lost and would appreciated any help that is offered here for this problem I've come across.

So I have a two column page, one side the filters and the other the list of things to be filtered. This page is created using the bit of html injected in to the DOM. I have a filter template and a list template and they both have their own controllers (filterCtrl and filterCtrl).

I understood that I needed to seperate the http request for the controllers in to factories, so at the moment an example factory and controller in my app look like this.

```
fpApp.controller('listController', ['$scope', 'eventsFactory',
    function($scope, eventsFactory) {
        eventsFactory.eventList().then(
            function(data){
                $scope.events = data;
            }
        );
    }
]);
```

and

```
fpApp.factory('eventsFactory', function ( $http ) {
    return {
        eventList: function() {
            return $http.get('/js/db/events.json')
            .then(
                function(result) {
                    return result.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

at the moment every thing is grand, I have a interface built up from partials and everything is outputting what I need. My problem is that I need to apply those filters to the list but have no idea how to get the information out of one controller in to the other controller or even one template to the other.. Once I'm able to get data from one to the other ill be good.

```
fpApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/grid");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('grid', {
            url: '/grid',
            views: {
                // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
                '': { templateUrl: '/templates/grid.html' },
                'filerList@grid': { 
                    templateUrl: '/templates/partials/filterList.html', 
                    controller: 'filterCtrl'
                },
                'viewSwitch@grid': { 
                    templateUrl: '/templates/partials/viewSwitch.html'
                },
                'eventList@grid': { 
                    templateUrl: '/templates/partials/eventList.html',
                    controller: 'listController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('list', {
            url: '/list',
            views: {
                // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
                '': { templateUrl: '/templates/list.html' },
                'filerList@list': { 
                    templateUrl: '/templates/partials/filterList.html',
                    controller: 'filterCtrl'
                },
                'viewSwitch@list': { 
                    templateUrl: '/templates/partials/viewSwitch.html'
                },
                'eventList@list': { 
                    templateUrl: '/templates/partials/eventList.html',
                    controller: 'listController'
                }
            }

        });
});
```

So in summary how do I affect the list controller when the  user is clicking filters in the filterController?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Search for "angularjs sharing data between controllers", there are plenty of ideas. A shared service, events are some.

Comment: I need more constructive information, how come? Have I structured it incorrectly? have I not provided enough information or explained really badly??